# Recursion within a method

Tags: python, class, oop, recursion

In my code I am counting the number of nodes in a complete binary tree and I decided to use a recursive approach. However, when I call my method within itself, I get NameError: name 'countNodes' is not defined.

```
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def countNodes(self, root: TreeNode, count = 0) -> int:
        if not root.left and not root.right:
            return 1
        else:
            count += countNodes(self, root.left, count) + countNodes(self, root.right, count)
```

Comment: Try `self.countNodes`.

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this question.

When accessing a `method` of the `class` instance inside the class you have to use `self.method`. So in your case you have to use `self.countNodes` instead of `countNodes`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought that since I was calling it within the method, I wouldn't have to add self before it. Thanks for the help.